# Can an indian citizen with US B1/B2 visitor visa travel to US from the UK

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, novice-travellers

After visiting the UK, can an Indian citizen with US B1/B2 visitor visa travel to the US?

Comment: Why wouldn't such a person be allowed to travel to the US?

Comment: You have a visa - it doesn't really matter where you're coming from - the normal rules apply. You just need to be able to assure the Immigration Officer that you'll behave and leave the USA when you're supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as they have a valid US visa. Touring the UK does not change anything about this.

Answer (score 3):

A US visa has no restrictions regarding where you can enter the US from. In other words, you can even enter by land from Canada or Mexico and it would not be an issue.

So yes, you can fly from the UK to the US.